# Insert Image in tabularx

Tags: graphics, tabularx

I am trying to insert an image in a tabularx using `\insertgraphics{}` and none of the solutions that I found on the internet seem to work. To do this, I am using a class with several commands, that are then called in the Latex Document.

The command to create the image is hardcoded in the class, and the image is inside a folder named `img`. I am getting several errors but the first one is `!Undefined control sequence`.

The class that I use is the following:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{tccv}
              [2012/11/09 v1.0
 Two Column Curriculum Vitae]

\LoadClass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\RequirePackage[hmargin=1.25cm,vmargin=1.25cm,twocolumn,columnsep=1.25cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{bookman,etoolbox,hyperref,needspace,tabularx,xcolor,fontawesome,makecell,graphicx}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\color[HTML]{303030} % Default foreground color
\definecolor{link}{HTML}{506060} % Hyperlinks
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=link,linkcolor=link}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\color[HTML]{0058B6}}
\setkomafont{section}{\scshape\Large\mdseries}

% In tccv \part must contain the subject of the curriculum vitae.
% The command will start a new page and output in onecolumn the
% subject (first and last name) with the hardcoded text
% "Curriculum vitae" under it.
\renewcommand\part[2]{%
  \twocolumn[%
    \vskip-\lastskip%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ c@{\hskip 0.25in} | X | X }
      {\usekomafont{part} \hfill #1} & {#2} & {\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}\includegrafics[width=\textwidth]{img/qrcode.png}\end{minipage}}
    \end{tabularx}
    \bigskip]}

% Renders a personal data box:
%
% |[
% \personal[optional: web site without scheme (no http:// prefix)]
%          {address}{phone number}{email}
% ]|
\newcommand\personal[4][]{%
    %\needspace{0.5\textheight}%
    \newdimen\boxwidth%
    \boxwidth=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax%
    \colorbox[HTML]{C7E2F2}{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\boxwidth}{c X}
    \faMapMarker  & {#2}\smallskip\\
    \faPhone     & {#3}\smallskip\\
    \faEnvelope      & \href{mailto:#4}{#4}
    \ifstrempty{#1}{}{\smallskip\\ \faLinkedin & \href{http://www.#1}{#1}}
    \end{tabularx}}}
```

The latex document I am using is:

```
\documentclass{tccv}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}

\begin{document}

\part{\makecell[r]{Name \\ Surname}}{\personal
    [linkedin.com]
    {Address }
    {+33 555 55 55 55}
    {someone@gmail.com}}

\end{document}
```

The image (can be any QR code) is:
[image]

And the result I am getting is the following:[image]

Comment: The command is `\includegraphics` not `\includegrafics` but also you should not have the surrounding  minipage.

Comment: you presumably got an _error_  about an undefined command, do not ignore error messages, after an error you should not look at the pdf at  other than possible use for debugging.

Comment: That was really dumb from my part :( Thanks for pointing out the mistake! To avoid being a useless post, do you know a simple way of vertically aligning the image?

Comment: easiest way is to use adjustbox package with its option to add extra keys to \includegraphics then you can specify things like `valign=t`

Comment: Great I will try it out. Thanks for helping this newbie in Latex hehe. If you want to post the comment as an answer I will mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is `\includegraphics` not `\includegrafics` but also you should not have the surrounding minipage

If you want to control alignment as mentioned in comments easiest way is to use `adjustbox` package with its option to add extra keys to `\includegraphics` then you can specify things like `valign=t`

Answer (score 1):

In his comment, @DavidCarlisle has already given you the idea. Here is a modified `.cls` file with the required corrections.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{tccv}
              [2012/11/09 v1.0
 Two Column Curriculum Vitae]

\LoadClass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\RequirePackage[hmargin=1.25cm,vmargin=1.25cm,twocolumn,columnsep=1.25cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{bookman,etoolbox,hyperref,needspace,tabularx,xcolor,fontawesome,makecell,graphicx}
\RequirePackage[export]{adjustbox}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\color[HTML]{303030} % Default foreground color
\definecolor{link}{HTML}{506060} % Hyperlinks
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=link,linkcolor=link}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\color[HTML]{0058B6}}
\setkomafont{section}{\scshape\Large\mdseries}

% In tccv \part must contain the subject of the curriculum vitae.
% The command will start a new page and output in onecolumn the
% subject (first and last name) with the hardcoded text
% "Curriculum vitae" under it.
\renewcommand\part[2]{%
  \twocolumn[%
    \vskip-\lastskip%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ c@{\hskip 0.25in} | X | X }
      {\usekomafont{part} \hfill #1} & {#2} & {\includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth,valign=m]{example-image}}
    \end{tabularx}
    \bigskip]}

% Renders a personal data box:
%
% |[
% \personal[optional: web site without scheme (no http:// prefix)]
%          {address}{phone number}{email}
% ]|
\newcommand\personal[4][]{%
    %\needspace{0.5\textheight}%
    \newdimen\boxwidth%
    \boxwidth=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax%
    \colorbox[HTML]{C7E2F2}{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\boxwidth}{c X}
    \faMapMarker  & {#2}\smallskip\\
    \faPhone     & {#3}\smallskip\\
    \faEnvelope      & \href{mailto:#4}{#4}
    \ifstrempty{#1}{}{\smallskip\\ \faLinkedin & \href{http://www.#1}{#1}}
    \end{tabularx}}}
```

Now, compiling your code:

```
\documentclass{tccv}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}

\begin{document}    

\part{\makecell[r]{Name \\ Surname}}{\personal
    [linkedin.com]
    {Address }
    {+33 555 55 55 55}
    {someone@gmail.com}}    

\end{document}
```

gives this result:

[image]